# Node js for making chatbot

Tags: node.js, bots

Can anyone recommend  tutorials which are helpful in learning node js for the back end of chatbot development?

Answer (score 1):

For a generic chatbot, you can use [Dialogflow](https://dialogflow.com/). They have a great documentation on Node.js and Express.js.
For messenger platform, Facebook already provides a sample code. 
You can check their sample [repo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform).
Here's a [sample code](https://github.com/fbsamples/messenger-platform-samples/tree/master/node) using Node.js and Express.js.

Answer (score 1):

Tutorials are available in large numbers in youtube.
I can give you a basic idea on it. First of all you must learn to integrate your agent from node.js file locally. If you have learnt that than next you will have to create another 4 js files  for handling request from user, for database query, for giving back response to the user and finally one for integrating the dialogFlow agent.Make all these 4 files a single node file by importing and expoting them as required. Its very fast and efficient to do the backend in node rather than python or Java. All the Best !